# Explain why watch 'jobs' does not work but watch 'ps' work?

Tags: command-line, ps, background-process, jobs, watch

`jobs` is my favorite command to see my codes which are running in the background. In order to check for them dynamically, I tend to type

```
watch 'jobs'
```

which does not display anything. However

```
watch 'ps'
```

works perfectly.
I have been doing the same mistake for months now.

I think understanding why the first does not work while the second works can help me to stop doing the same error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/460150/how-do-i-use-the-watch-and-jobs-commands-together-in-bash

Comment: A more useful question would be “**how** can I get it to work?” However why (in this case) is more interesting.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`jobs` is a built-in that reports on the state of the current shell: the commands that were backgrounded with that shell. `watch` runs a new shell for each execution, and that shell's `jobs` has no way of knowing what `watch`'s parent shell's jobs are. `ps` is an external command and it never used the shell's state.